# Check if value is between other values in list, and fetch values connected

Tags: python

What is the suggested way to build a list of values with belonging values?

Lets say I get a value; X = 3.14

I would then like to check where in my list the value is, and get the values belonging to that number.

Should I use "arrays in array" or is there a easier way?

In the list below I want to get the values 0,01 101 48 for example.

**Example of list:**

(List is created manually and will not be more than 50 "rows" and 6 "columns")

```
X value       a          b          c
   0         1,23       1,44       123
   1,1       0,79       0,7        486
   2,8       0,1        100        4,41
   3,5       0,01       101        48    <-- My value X is between 2,8 and 3,5
   4,9       etc        etc        etc
```

Comment: Do you want the value closest to X or the first value that is higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion. Two different solutions, depending on what you need.

```
rows = [
    [1, 1.23, 1.44, 123],
    [1.1, 0.79, 0.7, 486],
    [2.8, 0.1, 100, 4.41],
    [3.5, 0.01, 101, 48],
]

def get_gt_row(value):
    """ Returns first row where col 0 is greater than value. """
    for row in rows:
        if row[0] > value:
            return row[1:]  # Does not return col 0

def get_nearest_row(value):
    """ Returns row where col 0 is nearest to value. """
    return min(rows, key=lambda row: abs(value - row[0]))[1:]
```

Edit: variation of first option, using iterator.

```
def get_gt_row(value)
    return next((row[1:] for row in rows if row[0] > value), None)
```

Comment: There are also more complex libraries for matrix calculations, that allow you do more advanced stuff. I see a lot of people using Pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/). If your needs are about what you describe here, that seems like a massive overkill, though.